# Are there finite decimal numbers that cannot be represented by fixed point and /or floating point types?

Tags: floating-point, fixed-point

Let's be specific and talk about finite 32 bit decimal numbers, AKA any number which can fit within 32 bits, i.e not `1/3` as the fraction part continues infinitely like `0.333333...`.

Are there finite, 32 bit decimal numbers which **cannot** be represented by either Floating Pint numbers or Fixed Point integers? If the answer is yes, how can I figure out if a decimal number can be represented **accurately** by these two types or not?

Comment: `finite 32 bit decimal numbers` is not a well-defined mathematical concept. The way you describe it, 'any number which can fit within 32 bits, i.e. not 1/3 as the fraction part continues infinitely like 0.333...', seems to answer the question. If it can fit within 32 bits, it must be able to be represented, no? Not being 'trolly', I'm honestly not sure what you mean. Perhaps you can define it a bit more specifically.

Comment: from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic , `For example, one-tenth (0.1) and one-hundredth (0.01) can be represented only approximately by binary fixed-point or binary floating-point representations`.

Comment: Do you consider 0.1 or 0.01 'finite 32 bit decimal numbers'? I am unsure how you define 'finite 32 bit decimal numbers'.

Comment: I assume by "finite" you mean "terminating", i.e. numbers with a decimal expansion of finite length. (The "32 bits" is irrelevant.) And I assume you have in mind base-2 floating point, or fixed point with a scaling factor that is a power of 2.  Is that right?

Comment: If so: you can write every terminating decimal as a fraction whose denominator is a power of 10.  Reduce this fraction to lowest terms.  The answer is that if (and only if) the result has a denominator which is a power of 2, then it can be represented exactly in binary floating point (with some large enough exponent) or fixed point (with a large enough scaling factor).  Note this happens if and only if the denominator in lowest terms is *not* divisible by 5.

Comment: @NateEldredge i see, yes that's what I had it mind, thank you. Are there terminating numbers which CAN be represented by fixed point but not using floating point? how about the other way around?

Comment: No, the numbers that can be represented in either fixed or floating point are precisely those fractions for which the denominator in lowest terms is a power of 2 (aka *dyadic rationals*), i.e. `b/2^k`.  This can be represented exactly in fixed point as long as the scaling factor is at least `2^k`.  It can be represented exactly in floating point provided that the mantissa is at least `n` bits and the range of exponents includes `k-n`, where `n` is the number of bits in the integer `b`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: Of course for any *given* pair of fixed- and floating-point formats (with a choice of scaling factor, mantissa and exponent bits), there typically will be values that can be exactly represented in one but not the other.  But the set of values that can be exactly represented *in principle* is the same.

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example?

Comment: For instance `1/65536 = 0.0000152587890625` can be represented exactly in, say IEEE single-precision floating point (with a mantissa of 1 and an exponent of `-16`).  But it cannot be represented in fixed-point with a scaling factor of 4096, since it isn't an integer multiple of `1/4096`.

Comment: How can I choose the best scaling factor in this case? given a number (i.e like the one you used) how can I come up wit a scaling factor so the output is as precise and possible in fixed point?

Comment: Based on your previous comment, i'm guessing `1/scale` should be an integer multiple of the input and assure it reserves the correct number of bits for the fractions?